# ESP-IDF task interruption on measurement

Tags: c, task, interrupt, esp32, esp-idf

I have problem with my ESP32 controller. My system is using multiple tasks. I one I have measurement with HC-SR04. I suppose that I sometimes have interrupt during measurement.

I can't find documentation where interruptions between task are described.

**Here is sample code of my system:**

```
// code of measurement
int ultrasonic_measure()
{

    int64_t time_start = 0;
    int64_t time_end = 0;
    int64_t time_measured = 0;
    int64_t process_start_time = 0; 

    gpio_set_direction(TRIGGER_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_level(TRIGGER_PIN, 0);
    delay_ms(1);
    gpio_set_level(TRIGGER_PIN, 1);
    ets_delay_us(10);
    gpio_set_level(TRIGGER_PIN, 0);

    gpio_set_direction(TRIGGER_PIN, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);

    process_start_time = esp_timer_get_time();
    while (!gpio_get_level(TRIGGER_PIN))
    {
        if (timeout_expired(process_start_time, 120000))
        {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Timeout L");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    time_start = esp_timer_get_time();
    time_end = time_start;

    process_start_time = esp_timer_get_time();
    while (gpio_get_level(TRIGGER_PIN))
    {
        if (timeout_expired(process_start_time, 12000))
        {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "Timeout H");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    time_end = esp_timer_get_time();
    time_measured = time_end - time_start;
    int16_t distance = (time_measured / ROUNDTRIP) - CORRECTION;

    // elimination of overlimits
    distance = (distance < 70) ? 70 : distance;
    distance = (distance > 350) ? 350 : distance;
    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Final distance after correction: %dmm", distance);
    return distance;
}
```

```
void start_background_tasks()
{
    int priority = 10;
    // THIS IS TASK WITH MEASUREMENT
    xTaskCreate(&external_sensor_tasks, "external_sensor_tasks", 2560, NULL, 2 | priority, NULL);

    xTaskCreate(&update_key_task, "update_key_task", 2560, NULL, 2 | priority, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(&print_heap_task, "print_heap_task", 2560, NULL, 2 | priority, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(&output_update_task, "output_update_task", 2560, NULL, 2 | priority, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(&send_report_task, "send_report_task", 4096, NULL, 2 | priority, NULL);

    xTaskCreate(&websocket_task, "websocket_task", 4096, NULL, 2 | priority, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(&get_host_to_connect_task, "get_host_to_connect_task", 4096, NULL, 2 | priority, NULL);
}
```

I don't show my code of `external_sensor_tasks()` because it have other dependent logic (like save result etc.).

I'm beginner in ESP-IDF programming. When I try measures on Arduino UNO it works (I have one core and no interruptions). I have situation when my measures have returned 70mm distance.

Answer (score -1):

You cant do it this way (by polling). You need to use GPIO interrupt. In the interrupt handler, you need to read the value of the timer counter and then post (using a queue or direct task notifications) it to your measurement task.

Actually when you program in RTOS you need to forget about polling. You need to use IPC mechanisms. Programming in a multitasking environment is significantly different from naive Arduino style coding.

Comment: Could you send me more about solution -- eg. documentation, article in web. I don't understand all what you wrote. Bad is `ultrasonic_measure()` or `start_background_tasks()`?

Comment: @M.Liver Your comment shows that you have no knowledge about IPC and multitasking. Start from writing the PC software and learn queues, semaphores, mutexes etc etc. I cant do the multitasking programming course in the SO answer.